# Proof for a factorization is misunderstood by me.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Skipping a little ahead of the properties required to build this next property; consider this:

If a,b and c are any numbers, then =>
   a(b + c) = ab + ac

Now I assumed I understood this, however when looking at proving that $(x - 1)(x - 2) = x^2 - 3x + 2$ - I have found that I can not follow. 
Reading this proof from the bottom up makes perfect sense (or atleast feels comfortable) however from top down I feel like I am missing a link.

Please see:

$\begin{align}(x - 1)(x - 2) \\& = x(x - 2) + (-1)(x - 2) \\
& = (x)(x) + x(-2) + (-1)(x) + (-1)(-2)\\
& = x^2 + x[(-2) + (-1)] + 2\\
& = x^2 - 3x + 2 
\end{align}$

However if I read this from the top to bottom I get lost at line 1. How did he get to that from the fully factorized form.

Why does reading it from bottom to top feel natural.

This bugs me because I feel being able to reason from both ends can help you when stuck on case studies.

I have tried going back to basics like proving why any number multiplied by zero is zero or why a - b = b - a only if a=b and other such to make sure I understand addition and its properties as the building blocks and that subtraction, multiplication and division are built upon these. I feel comfortable with proving them...so what gives?

Comment: This may be helpful: $(b + c)a = ba + ca$. Take $a=(x - 2),b=x $ and $c=-1$.

Comment: Thank you. I should learn to try use symbols when lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t anything unnatural about it. You have

$$(x-1)(x-2) $$

and you can rewrite that using the Distributive Property which you’ve already noted in your post.

$$(\color{blue}{a}\color{green}{\pm b})\color{purple}{c} = \color{blue}{a}\color{purple}{c}\color{green}{\pm b}\color{purple}{c}$$

$$(\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{-1})\color{purple}{(x-2)} = \color{blue}{x}\color{purple}{(x-2)}\color{green}{-1}\color{purple}{(x-2)}$$

Comment: This was helpful. At this rate I should go back to high school. Got distracted by the noise. The colors helped. Thank you. Will mark as accepted.

Comment: Happens to all of us, glad the answer helped!